# Firebase security rules aren't working with functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a simple security rule set up which uses a function to determine if a user has access to a container in the system, every `container` and every `user` has a `owner` field on them, the following comparison is not working however:

query:

```
      await firebase.firestore().collection('containers').where('owner', '==', owner)
        .get()
        .then(({ docs }) => {
          const containers = getters.get_containers;
          const containersArray = docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));

          docs.forEach(doc => (containers[doc.id] = doc.data()));

          commit('set_containers', containers);
          commit('set_containers_array', containersArray);
        })
```

```
    function getUser() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
```

```
    function canAccessContainer(container_id) {
      return (getUser().data.owner == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/containers/$(container_id)).data.owner);
    }
```

```
    match /containers/{container_id} {
      allow read: if isAuthenticated() && canAccessContainer(container_id) <------- not working
      allow update: if isAuthenticated() && isUserInOrg();
      allow create: if isAuthenticated() && isUserInOrg() && !docExists(container_id, 'containers');
      allow delete: if isAuthenticated() && isUserInOrg();
    }
```

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  They are only meaningful when paired with app code that performs a query.  Please edit the question to show the query that isn't working the way you expect, along with any database documents required for the rule to operate.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone could reproduce the problem.

Comment: just realized I can use the resource variable. thank you.

Comment: If you're done with this question, please delete it or answer it yourself.

Comment: I'm honestly debating paying someone to do these for me, the docs make it impossible to figure out

Answer (score 0):

So after awhile of research, I've realized that I am using a lot of triggers on the back end to perform data transformation/manipulation in a lot of places.

These triggers are causing the "chain" of commands to silently fail, and really don't *need* security rules, basically setting the security rules to "isAuthenticated", "isUserInOrg", and matching the ownerId to the documents is enough to secure my app.